# Prolog list of predicates to list of lists

Tags: prolog

I have a list like: `[a([x,y]), b([u,v])]` and I want my result as `[[x,y], [u,v]]`.
Here is my code:

```
p(L, Res) :- 
    findall(X, (member(a(X), L)), A1), append([A1],[],L1),
    findall(Y, (member(b(Y), L)), A2), append(L1,[A2],L2),
    append(L2, Res).
```

This provides a partially good result but if my list is `[a([x,y]), c([u,v])]`, I would like the result to be: `[[x,y],[]]` and it is `[[x,y]]`.
 More examples:

```
 p([b([u,v]), a([x,y]), c([s,t]), d([e,f])], R)
```

The result I get: `[[x,y],[u,v]]` (as expected).

```
p([b([u,v]), z([x,y]), c([s,t]), d([e,f])], R)
```

The result I get: `[[u,v]]'`.
The result I want: `[[],[u,v]]`.

EDIT: Added more examples.

Comment: `append([A1],[],L1)` is the same as `[A1] = L1`, no?

Comment: What if you have `[b([x,y]), a([u,v])]`? Your predicate will produce `[[u,v], [x,y]]`. Is that the correct result? You should consider using `maplist` rather than `findall/3`.

Comment: Yes, `[[u,v], [x,y]]` is a correct result.

Comment: I have a *list like*.... what else might the list be like? Do you have other examples? Is it always two elements? Can it be more? I feel that the description of what you really need is incomplete. Are there always only two arguments to the terms (*e.g.*, `a(X,Y)` but not `a(X,Y,Z)`)?

Comment: There can be `a(X1,X2, .... Xn), b(....), c(..), ......, z` and I only search for a and b.

Comment: Your results are confusing. Why is the result of `p([b([u,v]), z([x,y]), c([s,t]), d([e,f])], R)` to be `R = [[], [u,v]]`? Based upon your prior description, I would have expected `R = [[u,v], [], [], []]`. Can you explain the purpose or meaning of your predicate?

Comment: In my predicate I search first for a. In `p([b([u,v]), z([x,y]), c([s,t]), d([e,f])], R)` it searches for a and find nothing so `[]` will be first, then it searches for b and finds `[u,v]`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. That's much more clear.

Comment: Can `a` or `b` occur more than once?

Comment: No they can't. Only one occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that it's clear what the problem statement really is, the solution is a little more understood. Your current solution is a little bit overdone and can be simplified. Also, the case where you want to have a `[]` element when the term isn't found falls a little outside of the paradigm, so can be handled as an exception. @AnsPiter has the right idea about using `=../2`, particularly if you need a solution that handles multiple occurrences of `a` and/or `b` in the list.

```
p(L, Res) :-
    find_term(a, L, As),     % Find the a terms
    find_term(b, L, Bs),     % Find the b terms
    append(As, Bs, Res).     % Append the results

find_term(F, L, Terms) :-
    Term =.. [F, X],
    findall(X, member(Term, L), Ts),
    (   Ts = []              % No results?
    ->  Terms = [[]]         % yes, then list is single element, []
    ;   Terms = Ts           % no, then result is the list of terms
    ).
```

Usage:

```
| ?- p([b([u,v]), z([x,y]), c([s,t]), d([e,f])], R).

R = [[],[u,v]]

yes
| ?-  p([b([x,y]), a([u,v])], L).

L = [[u,v],[x,y]]

yes
| ?-
```

The above solution will handle multiple occurrences of `a` and `b`.

If the problem really is restricted to one occurrence of each, then `findall/3` and `append/3` are way overkill and the predicate can be written:

```
p(L, [A,B]) :-
    (   member(a(A), L)
    ->  true
    ;   A = []
    ),
    (   member(b(B), L)
    ->  true
    ;   B = []
    ).
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Term =.. List :`**  Unifies List with a list whose head is the atom corresponding to the principal functor of
Term and whose tail is a list of the arguments of Term.

**Example :**

```
| ?- foo(n,n+1,n+2)=..List.
List = [foo,n,n+1,n+2] ? 

| ?- Term=..[foo,n,n+1,n+2].
Term = foo(n,n+1,n+2)
```

rely on your suggestion; you have a term contains a single argument List
so ;

```
p([],[]).                            
p([X|Xs], Result) :-
            X=..[F,Y],
            (%IF
            \+(F='c')-> % not(F=c)            
            Result=[Y|Res]; 
            %ELSE           
            Result = Res % Result = [Res] ==> [[x,y],[]]
            ),
            p(Xs,Res).
```

**Test :**

```
| ?- p([a([x,y]), c([u,v])],R).
R = [[x,y]] ? 
yes

| ?- p([a([x,y]), b([u,v])],R).
R = [[x,y],[u,v]] ? 
yes
```